# iOS testing an InApp Purchase a second time?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app that uses InApp purchases.  I have gone through all the steps necessary and everything seems to be working ok.  I am unclear on one issue though… how do I re-test an InAPP Purchase?

What I mean is I have a few different SKU's available, some when purchased cancel out others.  For example, I have Feature A that has a blue and red widget.  Then I have Feature B that includes a blue and red widget, but also adds a yellow one.

I successfully tested the InApp Purchase with the test account and bought Feature A, how do I clear the InApp and try my App by Purchasing Feature B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not clear the purchase history.

Create a new user for each different set of testing you want to run.

---

In your case, `MKStoreKit` keeps a record in the keychain and that is retained across app deletion. So, you need to call `removeAllKeychainData` on `MKStoreManager` to remove all of the old purchases.

Comment: That is what I did, but every time I run my app on the device it thinks I purchased the product.  I am logged out of the App Store.  What do I need to do?

Comment: You should log out before starting the app, then the app should ask you to login, that should be it. You obviously need to reinstall the app to remove the stored knowledge of previous purchase activations.

Comment: That is what I did, but it still thinks the feature was purchased. After I delete the App from the device I am re-installing it from xCode, is that ok?  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: No, that should be it. Does it ask you to login again? How are you storing the purchase history in the app?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you pointed me to something.  I am using MKStoreKit and in the App I am calling [MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"000000"] to see if it was already purchased.  I do this to disable the purchase button and notify the user that the feature is installed.  Could it be KStoreKit?  If so, what can it be?

Comment: Ahhh, YES!!!  I remember reading that somewhere!!  So, I am guessing that I need to only have this call during the testing.  Once my testing is complete, I can remove that call from my app… correct?

Comment: Yes, you only want it there of testing. You could consider using an `#ifdef DEBUG` statement to include / exclude